# SSIS Object Model LoadPackage Method issue

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to build an app that can read all connections from an dtsx file and updated respective values by user inputs.

Todo this i have started looking at http://ssisconfiguration.codeplex.com/ and taking this help and started doing an object model programming.

At the first, i am getting hickup and unable to load package. all the time am getting below eeror

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsGenericException was unhandled
```

Message=Failed to load XML from package file "C:\pkg_VID_DL_Business.dtsx" due to error 0xC00CE556 "Invalid at the top level of the document. Line 1, Column 1".  This happens when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into an XML document. This can be the result of either providing an incorrect file name to the LoadPackage method or the XML file specified having an incorrect format.

Comment: You need to provide more code for us to identify the problem. What is the target package's protection level?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I resolved this. This would work fine when you have Sql Server developer/standard/Enterprise versions installed along with your Visual studio. It doesn't work well with express edition due to the fact that it needs more SSIS assemblies to work with.